# Admob setAdListener not working

Tags: android, admob

I have created one banner ad, with (x) button will destroy adview. while I load ad again in same activity it wont calling adListener method. First time while app starts its working. So First time I can Visible (x) button while Ad appears but when I destroy ad using (x) button it destroy ad but for second time while I load ad, it loads Ad successfully but it is not calling 'adListener' so button is not going to visible.

This is my code:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >


                    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                        android:id="@+id/adView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
                        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
                    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_close_banner_ad"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@drawable/round_view">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_close_banner_ad"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_close_dialog" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Class File :

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();

mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
                super.onAdClosed();
            }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        Log.i("Ads", "onAdFailedToLoad");
        super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        Log.i("Ads", "onAdLeftApplication");
        super.onAdLeftApplication();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        Log.i("Ads", "onAdOpened");
        super.onAdOpened();
        adCloseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
        super.onAdLoaded();
        adCloseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

});


private void showBannerAd() {

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

// Destroy Ad while click on close Icon

```
 adCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mAdView != null){
                        mAdView.destroy();
                    }
                    adCloseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView#destroy()) about `destroy`

> Destroy the ad view. This method should be called in the parent Activity's onDestroy() method. **No other methods should be called on the ad view after destroy() is called.**

Instead of calling `destroy` set the visibility of adview to `View.Invisible` or `View.GONE`. In `onAdLoaded` of adView make the adView `VISIBLE`.

Comment: Thanks for response. I get Ad second time also but I want to visible my close button while ad starts and second time while I call for mAdView.loadAd(adRequest); it only show me ad but event of onAdLoaded not called.

Comment: I meant you should change your `adCloseButton`'s `onClick.` Ad is loaded does not mean that `adView` will work as it was working before destroy. Instead of calling `mAdView.destroy()` try once with `mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. I am sure you will get the desired result.